# Too many digits for UTM easting in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, utm

I am trying to get the x- and y-coordinate of a point layer in QGIS. So far, I have used the field calculator's function "$x" and "$y". I have read that easting coordinates should have 6 digits when using a UTM projection. However, when applying the functions mentioned, QGIS gives me a 7 digit easting coordinate. Does anyone know why this happens, and how I can obtain the 6 digit easting?

Projection: UTM 33 N
Example of coordinate: E: 1032624.32 N: 7862220.22

Comment: In the expression, add `round()` - something like`round ($x, 6)`

Comment: The number of digits in the coordinates depends on where you are. Especially for the y coordinate. For example, the y coordinates for Norway, in UTM 36N are all above 6,000,000, i.e. 7 digits.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! My question concerns the x-coordinate, not the y-coordinate. Rounding would remove decimals, but I cannot see how it would solve the problem. Digits and decimals are two different concepts.

Comment: You need to give an indication of the location in decimal degrees, the UTM zone, and the actual projection parameters before this can be answered.

Comment: Thank you. I have added this to the question. I hope it is the information you mean.

Comment: Please add a coordinate that you deem correct and the values that QGIS shows for it.

Comment: where is this point supposed to be located? With a Northing of 7862220 in UTM zone 33N, this would be in very northern Norway, perhaps in the Barents Sea.

Answer (score 1):

The Easting and Northing are distances from the origin of the zone. The origin is located 500,000 meters east of the central meridian of the zone, which is actually outside the zone. Thus any valid easting will have a value between 0 and 1,000,000*.  This is where you are getting the notion that an Easting is six digits. Since it's a distance and there is no reason for a distance to be an integer, it can have any number of digits past the decimal point. Whether these were meaningfully measured is a separate issue. For few more details, see [this page](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/natureofgeoinfo/c2_p23.html).

*Note that since the origin is outside the zone, there are values between 0 and 1,000,000 that are not in the zone.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that this is not UTM but rather a local variant. For example, there is a projection system called Gauss-Boaga, Zone 1 and Zone 2 used extensively in Italy. This has a seven digit easting- prefixed by 1 in the area corresponding roughly to UTM zone 32 and by 2 in UTM zone 33.

If you take off the "1" and the "2", then the map coordinates for points in this system are slightly different to UTM because they are based on a different datum. I think Arcgis calls these Monte Mario Italy 1 and Monte Mario Italy 2 (EPSG 3003 and 3004) and offers direct conversion between them, so I assume Qgis does the same.

I see that you believe the example point should have been in UTM zone 33 in which case it would have had a "2" in front of the easting, so your issue might be a bit different. Perhaps there are other variants of "the Monte Mario" projections used in another country or region but this might put you on the right track to solve the problem. I found that many data sets in Italy were based on this projection but poorly documented. However, the 7 digit easting was always a give-away.